Trace a silhouette of an image into a polygon
I have this example that draws a silhouette of an emoji on a canvas. I am looking to calculate a set of points to make it a physics body in Matter.js. I have tried to research some svg/image tracing algorithms but cant seem to wrap my head around them. I believe that finding the contours wont be so difficult as the image alpha data is available.


const emoji = document.querySelector("#emoji")
if (emoji instanceof HTMLCanvasElement) {
  const context = emoji.getContext("2d")
  if (context instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    const {
      clientWidth,
      clientHeight
    } = emoji
    context.save()
    const text = ""
    context.font = `${Math.floor(Math.min(clientWidth, clientHeight) * (2 / 3))}px monospace`
    const {
      actualBoundingBoxLeft,
      actualBoundingBoxRight,
      actualBoundingBoxAscent,
      actualBoundingBoxDescent,
    } = context.measureText(text)
    context.fillStyle = "black"
    context.fillRect(0, 0, clientWidth, clientHeight)
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in"
    context.fillText(
      text,
      clientWidth / 2 + (actualBoundingBoxLeft - actualBoundingBoxRight) / 2,
      clientHeight / 2 +
      (actualBoundingBoxAscent - actualBoundingBoxDescent) / 2,
    )
    context.restore()
  }
}
<canvas id="emoji" width="512" height="512" style="border: 1px solid red"></canvas>



A rough example of what I am looking for would be something like this:


You need to trace the image e.g via portace or simply use tracing options in graphic applications like inkscape. Then you can creaty a polygon approximation e.g via getPointAtlength()

@herrstrietzel, I am looking to do this in the browser as emojis will look different for different people, and with any emoji.

Please check the potrace.js link it runs in a browser. Keep in mind the traced result will also look differently on different browsers. For a consistent rendering it is probably easier to search for an existing emojii/icon repo on github and polygonize these icons beforehand
